# How to dynamically select columns in pandas based on input passed

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe like below

```
df.head(2)
A B C D E F
1 1 1 3 4 5
3 4 5 2 3 1
```

I want to dynamically select columns  based input passed .

**Input**

```
Enter number of columns?
 3

Enter  column names?
   A,E,C
```

**Expected Output**

```
 A  E  C
 1  4  1
 3  3  5
```

How can this be done in Python?

Comment: for integer based slicing use `iloc` : `df.iloc[:,:3]` for column labels use `loc` : `df.loc[:,['A','E','C']]`

Comment: @anky_91, I want pass the column  selections as inputs to the user.

Comment: In that case you can split the input on comma and create a list. `s="A,B,C"` , then split like: `s.split(',')` and pass it under `.loc[]` as shown above. BDW you should be able to handle cases where user inputs a column which is not there in the dataframe, in such cases use `df.reindex(columns=list_of_cols_after_split)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just ask for the column names.

```
cols = input("Column names?")
df = df[cols]
```

Note: columns will need to be entered as a list e.g. `['A', 'B', 'C']`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a slightly cleaner solution to Dance Party's (just so you don't need to input a list) you could do -

```
cols = input("Column names?")
cols = cols.split(', ')
df = df[cols]
```

This way your input can just be `A,E,C` and does not need to be a list

Answer (score 0):

```
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  1  1  1  3  4  5
1  3  4  5  2  3  1

select = str(input("insert required cols to display (coma seperated)"))
dfx[select.split(',')]
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the OP's question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works.  This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code.  You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.